# Android 11 Conversation Bubble Notification Coordinates

Tags: android-11

I have a chat list view in the bubble notifications (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/bubbles) which has a swipe listener requiring the position of the listview items.
In a regular activity i get this through:

```
int[] mylistCoords = new int[2];
mListView.getLocationOnScreen(mylistCoords);
```

and then subtract the offset of the listview from the touchpoint to match the hitbox of the elements.

```
int x = (int) motionEvent.getRawX() - listViewCoords[0];
int y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY() - listViewCoords[1]; 
View child;
for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
    child = mListView.getChildAt(i);
    child.getHitRect(rect);
    if (rect.contains(x, y)) {
        mDownView = child;
        break;
    }
}
```

Now in the bubble this does not work anymore because getLocationOnScreen does not compute the offset of the ConversationBubbleView to the actual main screen. Instead it only considers the ConversationBubbleView as the full screen and as a result the the touch point is offset by the same amount toward the bottom.
Any ideas how I can get access to these coordinates? I tried all sorts
of DisplayMetrics/Display shenanigans to compute the offset manually with values from view.getY() ect. but it seems the Bubble Conversation is a encapsulated thing on its own and I cannot access stuff around it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having this same problem, did you found any workaround? I think the only solution here is not to use the raw coordinates and only use the local coordinates, but this will require changing all the app to stop using getLocationOnScreen.